# Is there a way I can calculate the magnetic field strength a 5v relay produces?

Tags: relay, electromagnetism

So I know this question is rather specific, but im hoping someone can help me answer it.

I have a circuit that i've designed where I have an electromagnet thats switched on at a given point. The electromagnet was made by me and is terribly inefficient to produce. I figured a relay uses an electromagnet to complete a circuit, so the question is such: how can I calculate its magnetic field? I know it can measure it using an iphone app that makes use of the hall effect sensors but im hoping I can work it out roughly before i purchase a batch.

Comment: Break it open, count number of turns. L=N^2*Al.

Comment: If you know the current, and the geometry, you solve some differential equations with boundary conditions.   There are materials properties for the (steel?) that must be known, that will depend on the material history (so, did you anneal it?).